# I2C device (DS3231 RTC) not detected

Tags: pi-3, i2c, rtc

I have a small DS3231 RTC module, like the following, that I am trying to get to work with my PI 3 Model B. However it is not correctly being detected by the Pi.

[image: DS3231 RTC module]

Connected like so (ignore cables, they are for a 1-wire temp sensor)

[image]

Setup so far:

Enabled I2C with `raspi-config`

Contents of `/boot/config.txt`:

```
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=w1-gpio,gpiopin=22 # unrelated to this topic
```

Contents of `/etc/modules`:

```
i2c-dev
```

Output of `i2cdetect -y 1`

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

I have confirmed the wiring of the board. VCC, SDA, SCL on the chip itself goes to the correct pins on the PI.

I also tried to wire SDA directly to ground, in which case, `i2cdetect` shows every possible address (which is expected seems to indicate `i2cdetect`, and the pi i2c interface works fine).

With a multimeter, I tried to take some measurements of the SDA pin, while simultaneously running `i2cdetect`.  Doing this indicates that the SDA pin does go low for a short period of time when i2cdetect is run. I believe this indicates that the device is actually responding to the request of `i2cdetect` (as far as I understand it `i2cdetect` checks addresses by pulling SDA up, and waiting for a module signal its existence by pulling SDA down).

Running `timedatectl` I get no time on the RTC part.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Could the RTC module be faulty if so is there some way to verify that? Is there some setup steps I have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a clear photo of the connections between the Pi and the RTC?

Comment: @joan the module plugs directly into the PI with the headers on the module itself. Exactly like this (but stole the photo from elsewhere): https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0176/3274/products/20150218_091121_grande.jpg?v=1477646154

Comment: A photo would still be nice.  People have been off by a row of pins, some people have plugged them in at the wrong end of the expansion header.

Comment: Added an image of the connection.

Comment: Unfortunately I can see nothing wrong.  I suggest trying my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) to try to see what is going on.  Also confirm that the I2C pins are in I2C mode (e.g. `pigs mg 2 mg 3` should return 4 4).

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestion. In the end it turned out to be a defective module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a defective module.